# What differentiation between GetMessageA and GetMessageW function?

Tags: winapi

I am learning programming Window GUI. I don't know differentiation between 2 function GetMessageA and GetMessageW. I saw the GetMessage function have not any parameters involve to ANSI or Unicode.

Comment: Just use GetMessage().  The compiler sorts out whether you need the A or the W version based on a project setting.  Hopefully you are using the default, Project > Properties > General > Character Set  = Use Unicode Character Set.  So you get the W version.

Comment: @Hans I think that if the window is an ANSI window then you should be using `GetMessageA` with it. Of course, it would be somewhat unusual to have a Unicode app with an ANSI window.

Comment: GetMessage() has little to do with a window, 99.9% of the time you pass NULL.  Mixed window flavors should be avoided but is supported.

Comment: @HansPassant I've seen message loops that call `PeekMessage` to get the recipient window handle, then IsWindowUnicode passing that window handle, and then PeekMessageW or PeekMessageA. Which I don't understand. But then, if GetMessageW and GetMessageA are the same, one wonders why they exist.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan They both handle both types of windows, but they pass and return the data in the format that the app is compiled to use.

Comment: "*I saw the GetMessage function have not any parameters involve to ANSI or Unicode*" - no, but individual messages do, like `WM_GETTEXT` and any other messages that pass strings around. If you are creating an Ansi window, use `GetMessageA()`. If you are creating a Unicode window, use `GetMessageW()`.

Comment: Thank @RemyLebeau. After coding with more Window API, I think your answer is True.

Answer (score 1):

All older Win32 calls that involve strings are actually macros that expand to either a Unicode version or an ANSI version, based upon the "Character Set" property of the project.

GetMessage(...) will map to either GetMessageA(...) or GetMessageW(...) where the "A" version will handle messages that involve strings as ANSI formatted text and the "W" version will use UTF-16.